# Is there a way to get value from two range inputs and give the equation a custom value?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to get value from two range inputs and get a (not random) custom output e.g(`vmin` = 15, `vmax` = 20, `text` = 99 ; `vmin` = 15, `vmax` = 19, `text` = 7).
Is there a better way to do it ?

```html
<input id="smin" type="range" value="10" min="1" max="20" step="1"/>
<input id="smax" type="range" value="11" min="1" max="20" step="1"/>
<h1 id="text">0</h1>
```

```
var vmin = document.getElementById("smin").value; 
var vmax = document.getElementById("smax").value; 

if(vmin == 15 && vmax == 20)
    {
     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 99;
    }
if(vmin == 15 && vmax == 19)
    {
     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 7;
    }
```

Comment: I would go with this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55716470/3684265) and use `if else if` instead of two `if`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the values to match and the values to be output in an array.

Then you could iterate over this array to check if the ranges match any case, and if so, output the corresponding value.

This would scale very well if you add more conditions.

This also has the benefit to not set the value when no matches are found.

Here is an example with a function `execOnMatch` which takes a list of `[min, max, valueToOutput]` arrays and a function to call with the value when there is a match.

This function outputs another function that you can call with the `min/max` values of your ranges:

```js
const execOnMatch = (casesToHandle, onMatch) =>
  (vmin, vmax) => casesToHandle.forEach(([min, max, valueToOutput]) => {
    if (vmin == min && vmax == max) onMatch(valueToOutput);
  });

const text = document.getElementById('text');
const rangeMin = document.getElementById('smin');
const rangeMax = document.getElementById('smax');

const handler = execOnMatch(
  [[15, 20, 99], [15, 19, 7], [15, 15, 5], [17, 15, 8], [5, 15, 3], [7, 15, 1]],
  x => text.innerHTML = x
);

const handlerMin = x => handler(x, rangeMax.value);
const handlerMax = x => handler(rangeMin.value, x);
```

```html
<input id="smin" type="range" value="15" min="1" max="20" step="1" oninput="handlerMin(this.value)"/>
<input id="smax" type="range" value="15" min="1" max="20" step="1" oninput="handlerMax(this.value)"/>
<h1 id="text">0</h1>
```

Comment: I get the "rangeMax is not defined at HTMLInputElement.oninput"(same for rangeMin) error , any idea why ?

Comment: That fixed it but now I get "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" `x => text.innerHTML = x`

Comment: @hexer34, you have to make sure that your javascript is executed after the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

What is the logic to calculate this value? The better way is to build a function that receives vmin and vmax values as parameter, "does the math" and returns a value to be used in document.getElementById("text").innerHTML
Example:

```
function functionThatCalculatesTheValue(v1, v2) {
   var newValue = 0;
   // do something with v1 and v2 and set a value to newValue
   return newValue;
}

var vmin = document.getElementById("smin").value; 
var vmax = document.getElementById("smax").value;
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = functionThatCalculatesTheValue(vmin, vmax);
```